# Перенос кода из <script> в отдельный js файл

Tags: javascript, html, html5

**Есть такой код:**

```html
<script src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>
```

**Вопрос:** как мне код`<script src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>` использовать в js, а не прописывать в html файле.
**Можно ли прописать `<script src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>` в js файле?** Если нет, то как мне не
загрязнять html файл?

Comment: Напишите что хотите сделать? Вы не можете использовать JS в HTML без подключения JS

Comment: @ZaArs Я бы хотел из кода script сделать js код

Comment: Вопрос все еще открытый

Comment: Я поправил вопрос теперь будет понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо скачать этот файл script.js и подключить непосредственно из файловой системы по абсолютному или относительному пути.

Comment: Спасибо, я просто только начал разбираться в js и пока что не совсем знаю что к чему.

Comment: Почти в яблочко попали, я поправил вопрос теперь будет понятно))

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ПУТЬ К ФАЙЛУ С JS"></script>
```

Пример: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>`. Эта строка подключает  файл menu.js из папки js.

Comment: Спасибо за наглядный пример)

Comment: Почти в яблочко попали

Comment: Я поправил вопрос теперь будет понятно))